# Como obter marcadores próximos da localização do usuário?

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, gps

Boa noite

Quem conhece o aplicativo Tinder sabe que não é mostrado um mapa, mas sabe que ele pega a localização do usuário e utiliza para procurar pessoas que estejam próximas em um determinado raio. Gostaria de fazer a mesma coisa em minha aplicação Android, procurei por posts antigos no Stackoverflow e na internet sobre isso porém não encontrei respostas.

**EDIT**

No Google Maps API do Android ou na documentação do mesmo existe algum recurso nativo quanto a isto como existe no Google Maps API para JavaScript ou o desenvolvedor terá que realizar um select e cálculo para a solução?

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: no tinder fnciona assim, ele pega sua localizacao e fica chamando um servico enviando sua localizacao, e no servidor ele busca os pontos (pessoas) proximos a sua localizacao e te exibe, todo esse trabalho fica no servidor. ok? :)

Comment: Isso, mas queria um código como exemplo partindo do Google Maps API do Android. Obrigado pelo comentário.

Comment: no tinder creio que nao seu usa o mapa, ele acha os pontos proximos por um calculo e um select no banco mesmo.

Comment: O objetivo do SO é tirar dúvidas e também com certeza propor soluções concretas. No caso o que você tem pra nos mostrar, já tentou fazer alguma coisa? Como a sua pergunta está, pode parecer que você quer o código pronto.

Comment: Tentei procurando exemplos na Internet, porém nada concreto. Irei editar a pergunta colocando como base a documentação, se existe algum recurso na própria API que trata sobre esta questão. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estou estudando o mesmo problema no momento e encontrei esse paper:

[Finding Points Within a Distance of a Latitude/Longitude Using Bounding Coordinates](http://janmatuschek.de/LatitudeLongitudeBoundingCoordinates) - Por Jan Philip Matuschek

Ele aborda o problema de encontrar pontos geográficos que estão a uma certa distância(um raio) de um determinado ponto geográfico.

Já tem uma implementação em Java que é uma mão na roda, mas não é problema trivial e exige um pouco de matemática.

Comment: Obrigado Túlio, interessante que ainda não existe algum recurso nativo do Android que trate isso.